# Lodash _.setWith customize path

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I'm trying to figure out how to customize the path with lodash _.setWith. In the given example here:

```
var arr = 
[
  ['a'],
  ['a','b'],
  ['a','b','c'],
  ['a','b','c','d'],
]

var object = {};

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    _.setWith(object, arr[i], {'data' : {'path': 'path', 'title': 'title'}}, Object)
}

console.log(object)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6r6bp9ag/3/)

Outputs a structure like this:

```
{
  a: {
    data: {}
    b: {
      data: {}
      c: {
        data: {}
        d: {
          data: {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get something like this, with the customizer:

```
{
  a: {
    data: {}
    children: {
      b: {
        data: {}
        children: {
          c: {
            data: {}
            children: {
              d: {
                data: {}
                children: {}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to have ['a', 'children', 'b', 'children', 'c'].

You can transform your arr to something like this:

```
var arr = 
[
  ['a'],
  ['a','children','b'],
  ['a','children','b','children','c'],
  ['a','children','b','children','c','children','d'],
]
```

Another easier way to do it, is to transform every element to the string shorthand: ['a', 'b'] ->  'a.children.b', which I do in the following example by joining the array with .join('.children.').

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    _.setWith(
        object,
        arr[i].join('.children.'),
        {'data' : {'path': 'path', 'title': 'title'}},
        Object
    )
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z2j1t10q/

Answer (score 1):

You can add `'children'` to the path by using `_.zip()` with an array of `'children'`, flattening the result, and taking everything but the last item.

```js
var arr = 
[
  ['a'],
  ['a','b'],
  ['a','b','c'],
  ['a','b','c','d'],
]

var object = {};
var children = _.fill(new Array(arr.length), 'children'); // the children array size is like the longest path

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var path = _(arr[i])
    .zip(children) // zip it with the children array
    .flatten() // convert it to a single array
    .take((i + 1) * 2 - 1) // take everything but the last
    .value();

    _.setWith(object, path, {
      data : {'path': 'path', 'title': 'title'},
      children: {}
    }, Object)
}

console.log(object)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```